# spring oauth 2 create user mysql

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0, spring-jdbc

We are using this class for our oauth2 requirements and we can successfully add users and clients when we start the program but we would like to know is there any way we can add more clients and users later i.e. while the java program is running through a @request? Please help.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class Oauth2TwApplication {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Oauth2TwApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2AuthorizationConfig extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                    .jdbc(dataSource)
            ;
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            TokenStore tokenStore = new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);

            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
                throws Exception {

            oauthServer.checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(-10)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

            JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
            userDetailsService.setDataSource(dataSource);
            PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);

            if (!userDetailsService.userExists("user")) {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
                User userDetails = new User("user", encoder.encode("password"), authorities);

                userDetailsService.createUser(userDetails);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

MyViewControllers

```
@Controller
public class MyViewControllers  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }
}
```